# Multiple scans by key

Tags: c++, cuda

I have one 4-channel HSVL image - Hue, Saturation, Value (floats), Label (unsigned int).
The task is to compute an array of sums of Hues, Saturations, and Values, for each unique label. For example, I will be able to access the output Sum[of pixels with label 455] = { Hue: 500, Sat: 100, Val: 200 }. The size of the image is about 5 MP, and there are about 3000 different labels.

My idea is to have ~32 scans over parts of the image, that will produce 32 x nLabels sums. Then I can scan over the 32 partitions of the image, to arrive at nLabel sum structures.

Does a "scan by key?" algorithm exist that is a solution to this exact type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this by CUDA, the following could help.

Since you only need the sum values, I think what you need is "reduce by key". Thrust provides an implementation [`thrust::reduce_by_key()`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__reductions.html#ga1fd25c0e5e4cc0a6ab0dcb1f7f13a2ad) which could meet your needs.

But before using it, you have to sort all the pixels by the labels. This can be done with [`thrust::sort_by_key()`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__sorting.html#ga2bb765aeef19f6a04ca8b8ba11efff24)

You may also be interested in [`thrust::zip_iterator`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1zip__iterator.html), which can zip the 3 channels HSV into a single value iterator for sorting and reduction.

Comment: I checked reduce_by_key(), it seems that it only reduces (sums) consecutive elements with the same key, so if you have "enclaves" of data (highly probable), it will not produce the desired result.

Comment: Never mind - that's why you PSed to sort the pixels by key, which will make the algorithm provide the correct output.

Comment: You could also reduce_by_key first, then sort_by_key, then reduce_by_key again. You will save some time on sort due to the reduced number of elements, but you need to reduce_by_key twice. I don't know which way is quicker.